# AngularJS - ng-show using method continuously called

Tags: angularjs

To my understanding ng-show, like other bindings, should stop calling the associated method once the digest stabilizes.  With that in mind I would expect to see the following console.log() twice.  It is however logging once a second or so.

Is my understanding flawed, my implementation, or is this functioning as expected and I shouldn't worry about any negative performance impacts of such methods being called continuously?

**The method (in CoffeeScript)**

```
$scope.showThis = ->
    console.log("foobar")
    true
```

**The HTML tag with the ng-show**

```
<div ng-show="showThis()">hey, you can see me!</div>
```

Thanks for any insights =]

Comment: I bet you digest and apply are called as many times as showThis is called. And no, you should not worry. I would have used ng-if though, as it doesn't polute the dom.

Comment: Word, that's a good idea.  For others, ng-if removes the element itself from the HTML as opposed to just 'hiding' from the end user but leaving it in the HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is your correct understanding that ng-show would be called once the digest is 'stabilzed'. However, what you maybe fail to understand is that the apply digest cycle might be triggered by many things and so your ng-show would be called for this scope many times. You can debug and check that this scope's apply/digest is being called exactly as many times as your ng-show's method. There are no guarantees it should be called only once, twice or whatever times. As soon as a digest/apply cycle is triggered on your scope, you gonna get your console.log. Simple as that.

Of course, the reasons for triggering a digest/apply cycle might be multiple, but in my opinion eventually it should stop if you don't trigger browser events or don't do reloads or don't do some $timeout stuff. If it doesn't stop, then you messed up somewhere.

I created a Plunkr for you so you can check that in the normal case, it would be called once or twice and if you don't act on it, nothing happens. If you, however press the button, which updates a totally different scope value, it would trigger a scope digest/apply cycle and you would get an additional console.log:

http://plnkr.co/edit/x9I6VGP8eXtLGmT1Cuqu?p=preview

Comment: Thanks much, just wanted to ensure my understanding.  And now I understand... I messed up somewhere else =P

Comment: I discovered what my issue was earlier today (mind you I wasn't actively looking, just stumbled upon it): a scope variable had bound to it a Moment.js ticking clock, which meant that variable changed every second, firing off the digest.  Luckily it was something only needed in one specific instance allowing me to fix this issue in 90% of site.

Comment: Digest cycle even gets triggered if there is any mouse movement on screen, does anyone know reasoning behind it as it simply seems overkill.

Answer (score 2):

The way the digest cycle works is that every time a `$apply() or $digest()` is called it will go through all the watches that are setup (and expressions in directives are usually implemented by watches). If *ANY* watch fired, then it will run through ALL the watches again. It will keep doing this again and again until no more watches fire or until it's gone through 10 loops (at which point it throws an exception and fails).

Most any state change in angular will trigger a digest cycle (such as clicking on things, updating input values, or other events). You can expect watches to be called many many times throughout the lifetime of your application, this is why you need to make sure that you don't do any heavy computation in them.