# Displaying icon in a table using AngularJS depending on data from database?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display an icon in a table according to data from a database. I have a function that calls a query and returns a boolean if that data exists, if it does exist I would like to display an icon on a table. The problem I'm running into is that when I call that function, the function is executed infinite times and I'm not really sure why this is happening. Any help would be highly appreciated!

This is the table that will be displaying the icon:

```
<table class="table table striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> ... </th>
      <th> Exists? </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in myList">
        <td> ... </td>
        <td>
           <i ng-show="callFunctionThatReturnsBoolean(item)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true">
           </i>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-show`. When the `ng-show condition` satisfies based on the data then show the icon else don't.

I have written small piece of code based on your requirement.

In view,

```
<td> 
  <span ng-show='item.flag'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  {{item.flag}}
</td>
```

**Update:**

Updated plunker to use method for `ng-show`.

Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hOQg3O31xXJczQst1z7e?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you @Che! This didn't clearly answer my question as to why the function call was being called infinite times, but it led me to a different solution that got the job done :)

Comment: As per the code above, we don't have any details about what this method `callFunctionThatReturnsBoolean(item)` does. So I just wrote a demo to show an example about how to hide/show icons.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ng-show` should not be bound to a function call as it calls your function in every digest cycle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20915253/2419215.

But I guess the best approach would be to send back the model from the backend in its final version and don't make queries like this for certain list elements.